# Nginx + PHP5-FPM break some web app which works on Apache + PHP5

Tags: zend-framework, nginx, php

I have a vps with Debian 6.0.5, installed with Nginx + PHP5-FPM using package from [dotdeb](http://www.dotdeb.org/) using a [setup script](http://github.com/aatishnn/lempstack) introduced by a blog. Everything works like charm for my wordpress and phpmyadmin.

Now, I wanted to install beanstalkd into the vps, and decided to use some PHP web app to manage beanstalkd. I've installed [phpBeanstalkdAdmin](http://mnapoli.github.com/phpBeanstalkdAdmin/) and [Beanstalkd console](https://github.com/ptrofimov/beanstalk_console). Both failed to run properly.

phpBeanstalkdAdmin returns a page like

```
phpBeanstalkdAdmin
Home
About
layout()->content?>
```

Beanstalkd console displayed an empty tube once server is configured. Before that, the error message is also missing.

When I install both in my local machine running XAMPP, which is Apache + PHP5, and point the configuration to my vps' beanstalkd, it works. Further more, before configuration Beanstalkd console would display proper error message unlike when running on Nginx + PHP5-FPM.

I've tried to use XDebug and didn't find any error or anything wrong when stepping through both web app. Both web app utilizing Zend Framework. I didn't find any specific setup which is required to run Zend Framework on Nginx + PHP5-FPM, and have tried various addition of the basic configuration such as fixing `Path_Info` & `PHP_SELF`

I would really love to use Nginx instead of Apache for my vps as I have a small box.

Any insight or guide on this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you error logging enabled to the highest level in PHP? Have you logging enabled for fastcgi? Have you logging enabled for your webserver? If not, do so. Then report the errors you get or the logging information what actually happens.

Comment: Yes, error logging is enabled and all error except deprecated is logged. Like Tim's said, `short_open_tag` was the issue

Comment: Okay *that* specific issue won't give you any error message, true. But I though I had reviewed the source-code yesterday and I didn't see short-tags. Which file was that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the value of PHP's `short_open_tag` on both (should be listed in phpinfo). My guess is you need to turn it on for your VPS.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day. Never thought that Zend framework would allowed short tag, and I didn't take a closer at the html generated.